# How to find innerText or textContent of a specific dataset (data-*) using queryselector javascript?

Tags: javascript, dataset, bookmarklet, selectors-api

I don't know javascript, I am learning as I attempt a project.

I am having trouble reading `textContent` from a specific `dataset attribute`.

e.g. `<span data-field="member.firstName">JOHN</span>`
I need to read 'member.firstname', which should return "JOHN"

I am creating bookmarklets which also seems to be limiting my use.
I've found answers involving jQuery but I...
a. Don't understand the syntax.
b. Don't even know if I can use it in bookmarklets.

Using `queryselector`, the only results I have gotten other than `NULL` or `Undefined` involved using `nth-child[]` in my selector.

`javascript:(function(){console.log(document.querySelector('#calldetails-tab-summary > div > div.d3ui-col-6.calldetails-tab-content-col1 > fieldset:nth-child(1) > div.d3ui-tab-content-widget-content-readonly > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth- child(2) > span'));})();`

but the nodes are not constant in the container I am querying and this code only returns `<span data-field="member.firstName">JOHN</span>`

this snip of the html should be suitable as stand alone tester.

```
<div id="calldetails-tab-summary" class="d3ui-container ui-tabs-panel ui- 
widget-content ui-corner-bottom" data-tabkey="E1-SUMMARY">
<div class="d3ui-row">
<div class="d3ui-col-6 calldetails-tab-content-col1"><fieldset data- 
groupkey="E1-SUMMARY-MEMBER-SUMMARY" data-editable="true" class="d3ui-tab- 
content-widget " title="Member Summary">
<div class="d3ui-tab-content-widget-header">
<div class="d3ui-tab-content-widget-header-text ">Member Summary</div>
</div>
<div class="d3ui-tab-content-widget-content-readonly">
<div data-audit="" class="" data-fieldkey="memberName" title="Name">
<label>Name</label>
<span class="">
<span data-field="member.firstName">JOHN</span>
</span>
<span class="">
<span data-field="member.lastName">DOE</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
alert(document.querySelectorAll("[data-field='member.firstName']")[0].innerText);
```

Link to fiddle (ES6): https://jsfiddle.net/hcrov42e/

Comment: this did exactly what i was looking for. one question, does this rely on the dataset being in the same position every time? because that would cause a problem with my further queries in the container as they change position depending on how many fields have data set in them.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what You mean by "same position". Query looks for matches in the entire document so position of span or div should not be a problem. What you probably should do before triggering this query is check if there is an element with that data field (just by comparing .length >0 instead of selecting [0]).

Comment: i ask because i dont know what the `[0]` is for, if it is a position in an array?

Comment: It returns array of all correct elements. Assuming there is only one element with that data I used [0].

Comment: I see, thank you for the perfect streamlined answer and explaining it to me.

Answer (score 0):

[Dataset MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#firstname');
console.log(el.dataset.field)
```

```html
<span id="firstname" data-field="member.firstName">JOHN</span>
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null`-edit-

Comment: -edit- was i supposed to run that code against the website i am working with, or against your modified html? i cannot change the html of the website to suit my query. the website i am working with did not give the span an id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  var firstNameSpan = document.querySelector("[data-field~='member.firstName']");

  var lastNameSpan = document.querySelector("[data-field~='member.lastName']");

 console.log(firstNameSpan.innerHTML);  // this will be John
 console.log(lastNameSpan.innerHTML);  // this will be Doe
```

For working example chceck this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c_Dhananjay/crmpLj62/

Comment: Glad to help you :)